# onClick div around another button?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Cta component that gets used all over the site. It has alot of functionality already coded that i need (among other things: passes in "data", and navigates to page A).  However, for this specific CTA, i also need to do something specific onClick(handleDismiss()) (close the banner its on) that isn't coded into the original button component.

So I've done it like this:

```
   <div role="button" onClick={() => handleDismiss()} onKeyDown={() => handleDismissButton()} tabIndex={0}>
     <Cta data={data} />
   </div>
```

This works and takes care of all the ESlint rules. However, i'm wondering if this isn't best practice and if theres another way? Should i have in fact add this one time code into the Cta component?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: This is a valid approach to do this.

There's no rule which is dictating you should add this one-time code into the `Cta` comp. itself.

In this use-case, adding the `handleDismiss` directly to the Cta component would create additional complexity and potentially make the code more difficult to maintain in the future because it is specific to this usage and won't be reused.

Therefore, keeping with the wrapper div approach appears appropriate and meets your criteria given the context you've supplied. It's practical method that lets you get the desired functionality you want without complicating the code too much.

One thing, as a suggestion and note for you is to use `Semantic HTML Elements`:

It's always recommended to use a `semantic HTML element` that conveys the function of a button or any other interactive element when wrapping it. For improved accessibility and semantics, you might utilize a `button` element rather than a `div`.